# Is a Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Show that the vector space, $P_n$, of all the real polynomial functions of degree less than n, is a Banach Space for any norm define.

I think if I prove that $P_{n}$ is a Banach Space with the norm $|| |p| || = ||(a_0,a_1,...,a_n-1)||$, where $(a_0,a_1,...,a_{n-1})$ is a vector in $R^n$ wich coordinates are the coeficients of  $p$ and $||.||$ is any norm in $R^n$, I can prove that is for any norm define in it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It's a finite dimensional real vector space, so all you need to show is that all norms are equivalent over $\mathbb R^n$ and any norm on $P_n$ will arise as a norm over $\mathbb R^n$ under the isomorphism $\phi : P_n \to \mathbb R^n$ you chose. If you want me to give you the details, ask for them. They can probably be found in your notes if you have any.

P.S. I think $P_n$ being the space of polynomials of degree less than $n$ includes degree $n$ polynomials, at least that's what I always see so I think of it as a standard.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Yes all norms are equivialent over $R^n$. To see that is complete I chose a $(f_{n})$ cauchy sequence, then for all ϵ>0 exist $n_0 ∈ N$ such that if $m,n > n_{0}$ then $d(f_{n},f_{m})= ||f_{n}-f_{m}|| < ϵ $ But $f_{n}(x)$ lies in $R$, becouse we are considere real polynomial functions, but $R$ is complete, so $f_{n}$ converge to some element in $R$, then the problem is to prove that $ lim_{n}f_{n}(x)=f(x)$  exist, right?

Comment: Um... I don't see what your point is, but the standard proof that $\mathbb R^k$ is complete uses the usual norm $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}$. In this case, if we denote by $x_n = (x_n^1, \dots, x_n^k)$ the sequence $x_n$, if $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, so is $x_n^1$, hence $x_n^1$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}^1$. Now $x_{n_k}$ is still Cauchy, hence $x_{n_k}^2$ is Cauchy, and admits a convergent subsequence. Repeating this step for all components gives you a sub-sub-$\dots$-sub-sequence of $x_n$ which converges component-wise, hence converges. That is the standard proof.

Comment: If you took the norm of $a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_n x^n$ to be $\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i^2}$ you could use this argument without mentioning $\mathbb R^n$ anywhere, but then you would have to show that all norms over $P_n$ are equivalent.